# How do I put a picture on top of another image,bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying put two images on top of each other in the bootstrap Such a figure:

[image]

So I used the following:

Html code is:

```
<div class="thumb">
 <img src="images/paner1.png" class="img-thumbnail none_border"  width="1650" >
 <div class="collection">
    <img src="images/logo.png"  width="226px"  />

 </div>
```

Css code is:

```
.collection{
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;}

.thumb{
position: relative;
border: none;}
```

But the problem is that the image **logo** When you minimize the screen moves to the wrong place and completely different from the real place when the screen is in the greatest measured ..

So how can I make two images in their original condition in all cases of the screen?!

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: prefer:http://jsfiddle.net/Mariam_Al_kassar/9n8xU/
When you change the size of the screen image is changing placecoporate.png and take the wrong place and the picture becomes inhomogeneous :(

Comment: Hello. I know this is from 4 years ago, but did you find a solution for this? Thanks.